# Can't access to shared folder from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, file-sharing

I have 3 computers in my network. One computer with shared folder running Windows 8, another computer with Windows 8 and the last with Windows 7.

The two Windows 8 computers can access to the two other computers (Windows 8 and Windows 7).

But the Windows 7 computer can't access to both Windows 8 computers. When I try to access from my Windows 7 computer to Windows 8 computer I get error:

> Error code: 0x800704cf
>   The network location cannot be reached.

But the ping succeed from Windows 7 to Windows 8.

What should I do?

**EDIT:**
machine status:

- All the machine runs with 64 bit version of Windows.
- The Windows 7 machine have Service Pack 1.
- When I turn off the firewall the error still there.
- File and Printer Sharing is checked in all machines.
- I don't have homegroup and all the computers have the same workgroup name. When I try to access to machine I enter the computer name or IP.
- Network Discovery is ON in all computers.
- Password protected sharing is ON in all computers.
- I have credentials for the others machines in my network.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete error message.

Comment: What are the error logs on the Win7 machine saying?

Comment: @rastaBob When I try to connect it show me a message with the error in the question. How can I get the error logs in Windows 7?

Comment: Go to: Control Panel\System and Security\Administrative Tools\Event Viewer\Windows Logs. Then check the System log for the above error code. Hopefully it gives you more info than what you have above.